# Convert ArrayList into 2D array containing varying lengths of arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, indexing, varying

So I have:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

Which contains an x number of ArrayLists which contain another y number of Strings.. To demonstrate:

```
Index 0:
  String 1
  String 2
  String 3
Index 1:
  String 4
Index 2:
Index 3:
  String 5
  String 6
```

Where index refers to the array index containing a string.

How can I transform this into a 2D array which looks like:

```
{{String1, String2, String3},{String4}, {}, {String5, String6}}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Here is an answer which involves an array of int (primitive data types) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62973865/6648326

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
String[][] array = new String[arrayList.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> row = arrayList.get(i);
    array[i] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
}
```

where `arrayList` is your `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` (or any `List<List<String>>`, change the first line inside the `for` loop accordingly)

Comment: What if i have ArrayList<String[]> and want to convert it into a 2D array ?

Comment: sorry, I missed this, you may have figured it out by now... 

Anyway, it's simply

`String[][] array2D = new String[arrayList.size()][];
 for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {
    String[] row = arrayList.get(i);
    array2D[i] = row;
}`

Comment: not working for me. final 2d array has only one column for each row.

Comment: how are you checking and what does your input look like?

Answer (score 60):

Welcome to a world with Java 8!

It only took me all night with no sleep to learn what was needed to write this one freaking line of code. I'm sure it is already out there somewhere but I couldn't find it. So I'm sharing my hours and hours of research, enjoy. Woot!

Assuming:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
// populate this list here
```

(Or, rather, in Java 8:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList();
//Populate
```

)

Then all you need is:

```
String[][] stringArray = mainList.stream().map(u -> u.toArray(new String[0])).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Bam! One line.

I'm not sure how fast it is compared to the other options. But this is how it works:

1. Take a stream of the `mainList` 2D ArrayList. This stream is a bit like a Vector hooked up with a LinkedList and they had a kid. And that kid, later in life, dosed up on some [NZT-48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limitless). I digress; `mainList.stream()` is returning a stream of `ArrayList<String>` elements. Or in even geekier speak: `mainList.stream()` returns a `Stream<ArrayList<String>>`, sorta.
2. Call the `.map` function on that stream which will return a new stream with contents that match a new type specified by the parameters passed into `map`. This `map` function will covert each element in our stream for us. It has a built in `foreach` statement. In order to accomplish this; the `map` function takes a lambda expression as its parameter. A [Lambda expression](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html) is like a simple inline one-line function. Which has two data types [gettin' Jiggy wit it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettin%27_Jiggy_wit_It). First is the type of data in the stream upon which it was called (`mainList.stream()`).  The next type is the type of data it will map it out to, which is in the right half of the lambda expression: `u -> u.toArray(new String[0])`. Here `u` is an identifier you choose just like when using a `foreach` statement. The first half declares this like so: `u ->`. And like a `foreach`, the variable `u` will now be each element in the stream as it iterates through the stream.  Thus, `u` is of the data type that the elements of the original stream are because it *is* them. The right half of the Lambda expression shows what to do with each element: `u.toArray(new String[0])`. With the results being stored in their rightful place in a new stream. In this case we convert it to a `String[]`.. because after all, this is a 2D array of `String`.. or rather from this point in the code, a 1D array of `String[]` (string arrays). Keep in mind that `u` is ultimately an `ArrayList`. Note, calling `toArray` from an `ArrayList` object will create a new array of the type passed into it. Here we pass in `new String[0]`. Therefore it creates a new array of type `String[]` and with length equal to the length of the ArrayList `u`. It then fills this new array of strings with the contents of the `ArrayList` and returns it. Which leaves the Lambda expression and back into `map`. Then, `map` collects these string arrays and creates a new stream with them, it has the associated type `String[]` and then returns it. Therefore, `map` returns a `Stream<String[]>`, in this case. (Well, actually it returns a `Stream<Object[]>`, which is confusing and needs conversion, see below)
3. Therefore we just need to call `toArray` on that new stream of arrays of strings. But calling `toArray` on a `Stream<Object[]>` is a bit different than calling it on an `ArrayList<String>`, as we did before. Here, we have to use a function reference confusing thing. It grabs the type from this: `String[][]::new`.  That `new` function has type `String[][]`. Basically, since the function is called *toArray* it will always be an `[]` of some sort. In our case since the data inside was yet another array we just add on another `[]`. I'm not sure why the NZT-48 wasn't working on this one. I would have expected a default call to `toArray()` would be enough, seeing that its a stream and all. A stream thats specifically `Stream<String[]>`. Anyone know why `map` actually returns a `Stream<Object[]>` and not a stream of the type returned by the Lambda expression inside?
4. Now that we got the `toArray` from our `mainList` stream acting properly. We can just dump it into a local variable easy enough: `String[][] stringArray = mainList.stream...`

## Convert 2D ArrayList of Integers to 2D array of primitive ints

Now, I know some of you are out there going. "This doesn't work for ints!" As was my case. It does however work for "[Ents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ent)", see above.  But, if you want a 2D primitive `int` array from a 2D `ArrayList` of `Integer` (ie. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`). You gotta change around that middle[earth] mapping. Keep in mind that ArrayLists can't have primitive types. Therefore you can't call `toArray` on the `ArrayList<Integer>` and expect to get a `int[]`. You will need to map it out... again.

```
int[][] intArray = mainList.stream().map(  u  ->  u.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray()  ).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

I tried to space it out for readability. But you can see here that we have to go through the same whole mapping process again. This time we can't just simply call `toArray` on the ArrayList `u`; as with the above example. Here we are calling `toArray` on a `Stream` not an `ArrayList`. So for some reason we don't have to pass it a "type", I think its taking brain steroids. Therefore, we can take the default option; where it takes a hit of that NZT-48 and figures out the obvious for us this [run]time. I'm not sure why it couldn't just do that on the above example. Oh, thats right.... ArrayLists don't take NZT-48 like Streams do. Wait... what am I even talking about here?

Annnyhoow, because streams are sooo smart. Like [Sheldon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Cooper), we need a whole new protocol to deal with them. Apparently advanced intelligence doesn't always mean easy to deal with. Therefore, this new `mapToInt` is needed to make a new `Stream` which we can use its smarter `toArray`. And the `i->i` Lambda expression in `mapToInt` is a simple unboxing of the `Integer` to `int`, using the implicit auto-unboxing that allows `int = Integer`. Which, now, seems like a dumb trivial thing to do, as if intelligence has its limits. During my adventure learning all this: I actually tried to use `mapToInt(null)` because I expected a default behavior. Not an argument!! (*cough* Sheldon *cough*)  Then I say in my best [Husker](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Husker) valley girl accent, "Afterall, it *is* called `mapToInt`, I would guess that, like, 84% of the time ([42](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything&oq=the+ans&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i67j0l9.6690.8319.0.9719.9.8.1.0.0.0.118.676.4j3.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.8.678.9U0H1oblBd4)x2) it will be, like, passed `i->i` by, like, everyone, so like, omgawd!"  Needless to say, I feel a bit... like.. [this guy](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f7/4c/30/f74c30483999ca714008c2b2c0f1987a.jpg). I don't know, why it doesn't work that way.

Well, I'm red-eye and half delirious and half asleep. I probably made some mistakes; please troll them out so I can fix them and let me know if there is an even better way!

PT

Comment: Since `map` takes a Lambda (which reputedly knows the data type of each side of the Lambda), it should be able to pass that data type info onward. So, despite my crazy ramblings, I still really would like an answer to those two questions mentioned above:
1) Why does `map` actually return a `Stream<Object[]>`  as a default behavior and not a stream of the type returned by the Lambda expression inside?   ---   
2) Why does `mapToInt` not have a default usage of `i->i` ?

Comment: I used your answer https://pastebin.com/iNkwetbW. I'm getting a warning that it overrides multiple methods when I coded this in IntelliJ IDEA. How do I remove those warnings?

Comment: Overrides? That seems strange. I wouldn't say that this line of code is overriding anything. But I have no clue what IntelliJ IDEA is and the environment in which it stands. I can't be of any help. I hope someone else on here reads this and can help you out. Maybe start breaking the statement down to its smaller parts and test them individually and see where the problem is. For instance, try pulling a `.stream()` from the `ArrayList` and just print it to the screen to make sure that parts works.. then move on to the `.map()`... etc

Comment: I'd go with new ArrayList<>() (rather than new ArrayList())

Comment: If anyone needs working code to convert a 2d array of int to a list - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62973891/6648326

Answer (score 6):

You can use `toArray()` method to convert an ArrayList to an array. Since you have ArrayList within ArrayList, you will need to iterate over each element and apply this method.

Something like this:-

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
// populate this list here
//more code

// convert to an array of ArrayLists
ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (ArrayList<String> stringList : mainList){
    tempList.add((String[])stringList.toArray());
}

//Convert to array of arrays - 2D array
String [][]list = (String[][])tempList.toArray();
```

You can find more about `toArray()` [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
public String[][] toArray(List<List<String>> list) {
    String[][] r = new String[list.size()][];
    int i = 0;
    for (List<String> next : list) {
       r[i++] = next.toArray(new String[next.size()]);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
          ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
          ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
          a.add("Hello");
          b.add("Hell");
          list.add(a);
          list.add(b);
          Object[][] array = new Object[list.size()][];
          Iterator<ArrayList<String>> iterator = list.iterator();
          int i = 0;
          while(iterator.hasNext()){
              array[i] = iterator.next().toArray();
          }
```

You can use the below snippet to convert Object[] to String[]

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[][] array = new int[list.size()][]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        array[i] = new int[list.get(i).size()]; 
    } 
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) { 
            array[i][j] = list.get(i).get(j); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This complete mini program code answers this question in quite self-explanatory way.Just paste and run it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListTo2Darray {

    public String[][] toArray(List<List<?>> list) {
    String[][] r = new String[list.size()][];
    int i = 0;
    for (List<?> next : list) {
       r[i++] = next.toArray(new String[next.size()]);
    }
    return r;
}

    public static void main(String[]arg){
        String[][] sham;

        List<List<?>> mList = new ArrayList();

        List<String> a= new ArrayList();
        List<String> b= new ArrayList();
        a.add("a");  a.add("a");
        b.add("b");  b.add("b");
        mList.add(a); mList.add(b); 

        ListTo2Darray mt= new ListTo2Darray();
        sham=   mt.toArray(mList);

        System.out.println(sham[0][0]);
        System.out.println(sham[0][1]);
        System.out.println(sham[1][0]);
        System.out.println(sham[1][1]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queries=[[1,5,3],[4,8,7],[6,9,1]]
h=queries.size();

        for(i=0;i<h;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                y[i][j]= ( ( queries.get(i) ).get(j) );
            }  
        }
```

What it will do is that at y[i][j] at this statement firstly queries.get(i) will pick the first block of list i.e, at i=0 it will pick [1,5,3] and then at j=0 it will pick 1 from [1,5,3], and so on..

loop explanation:
y[][]=[ 1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1  ]

Note: Replace the queries with your given array.

Please let me know if it works or should i give another way to solve the problem