# Convert Collection<List<T>> to 2D array T[][]

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert ArrayList into 2D array containing varying lengths of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043209/convert-arraylist-into-2d-array-containing-varying-lengths-of-arrays)

How can I convert a `Collection<List<Foo>>` into a 2D array of type `Foo[][]`?

I'm trying to use the `toArray` method, but I'm not sure about the syntax. For instance, this doesn't work:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
Collection<List<Foo>> permuted = Collections2.permutations(bar);
Foo[][] permutedArray = permuted.toArray(new Foo[10][10]);//exception here
```

it's throwing `ArrayStoreException`. In this case, what should be the type for `permutedArray`?

Comment: do all lists have a fixed size or not?

Comment: yes they do, let suppose the size is `size`. But can the size be determined at runtime?

Comment: One question: is `T` generic type or is it specific class?

Comment: It's a specific class. I changed the question to remove the ambiguity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.toArray` can only convert the collection into a `List<Foo>[]`. You need to call `.toArray` on each element of the array of list again to really get a `Foo[][]`.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<Foo>[] permutedList = permuted.toArray(new List[10]);
    final Foo[][] permutedArray = new Foo[10][10];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        permutedArray[j] = permutedList[j].toArray(new Foo[10]);
    }
```

Comment: there's an error on `new List<Foo>[10]` : `Cannot create a generic array of List<Foo>`

Comment: Have you defined Foo? `public <Foo> Foo[][] deconstruct(Collection<List<Foo>> colleciton)` should work

Comment: yes Foo is defined, strange though...

Comment: @Chin: Check update. It seems the only way to work is to use unchecked conversion.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it might make more sense to do a set of nested loops:

```
//Untested, I might have made some silly mistake
T[][] array = new T[collection.size()[];
int collection = 0;
int list = 0;

for(List<T> list : collection)
{
  list = 0;
  array[collection] = new T[list.size()];
  for(T t : list)
    array[collection][list++] = t;

  collection++;
}
```

The "toArray" method is handy, but because of Generic types I usually find it frustrating to work with. Utility methods like this generally read easier and avoid the problems you're running into.

*EDIT: I should note: you need to know or cast T. It will generate an unchecked types exception (which of course is unchecked!).*

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like the following generic utility function:

```
public static <T> T[][] asMatrix(
    Collection<? extends Collection<? extends T>> source,
    T[][] target) {

    // Create a zero-sized array which we may need when converting a row.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T[] emptyRow =
        (T[])Array.newInstance(target.getClass().getComponentType().getComponentType(), 0);

    List<T[]> rows = new ArrayList<T[]>(source.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (Collection<? extends T> row : source) {
        T[] targetRow = i < target.length ? target[i] : null;
        rows.add(row.toArray(targetRow != null ? targetRow : emptyRow));
        i += 1;
    }
    return rows.toArray(target);
}
```

Usage:

```
Collection<List<Foo>> permuted = ...;
Foo[][] result = asMatrix(permuted, new Foo[][] {});
```

The way it works is to visit each sub collection (i.e., row), converting it into an array. We cache these arrays in a collection. We then ask that collection to convert itself into an array, which we use as the result of the function.

The benefits of this utility function are:

1. It uses `Collection.toArray` for all of the array construction and copying.
2. The function is generic and so can handle any kind of reference type (unfortunately native types like `int`, `long`, etc., will require more work).
3. You pass in the target array, which might even be preallocated to a certain size, behaving exactly the same as `Collection.toArray` does.
4. The function is tolerant of collections that change their size concurrently (as long as the collections are themselves tolerant).
5. The conversion is type safe *and* type strict.

More examples:

```
List<List<Integer>> list =
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(3, 4));

Integer[][] result;

result = asMatrix(list, new Integer[][] {});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));

result = asMatrix(list, new Integer[][] {new Integer[] {9, 9, 9, 9}, null});
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, null, 9], [3, 4]]
```