# "Block" ArrayList size

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So, I have an **2D ArrayList** thanks to this question: [How to create a Multidimensional ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401850/how-to-create-a-multidimensional-arraylist-in-java)
And, now I have it **inside a 2D array**, thanks to this question: [Convert ArrayList into 2D array containing varying lengths of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043209/convert-arraylist-into-2d-array-containing-varying-lengths-of-arrays)

I need my ArrayList to have a "**blocked width size**" (bws), that is, when the size of the ArrayList reaches that number (bws), it "breaks" the ArrayList line:

[image]

However, I have no ideia how to do it :(.

EDIT:

So, what should I do?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Question edited at the last line.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I think what you should do is write some code. Then show it to us and explain which part you're having difficulty with. Then we'll be able to help you make progress.

Comment: You aren't been rude :D. I just can't think of anything in about 2 days stuck on this.

Comment: @CrazyProgrammer Even if you're not able to write actual code on this problem, I strongly suggest that you write pseudocode that will describe how you would mentally approach doing such an operation step-by-step. We can then help convert it to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify much about the interface, so I'll just define some basics from which you could go on and develop more:

- The list with blocked width should be able to **add** elements
- One should be able to **access** an arbitrary row in the list

You could go on and define an **iterator**, implement various **collection interfaces** and whatever you want.

Note that any client code should not be concerned about **implementation details**. Carefully think about the interface of your list with blocked width. The interface tells the client everything it needs to now. How the interface is implemented is solely the concern of the implementing class. That said, you can easily store your two-dimensional list with blocked-width as a single, plain `java.util.List`. But hide that list from your clients.

Here's the code I propose:

```
public class BlockedWidthList<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockedWidthList<Integer> myList = new BlockedWidthList<Integer>(6);
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            myList.add(i);
        for(Integer entry : myList.getRow(2))
            System.out.println(entry);
    }

    /** @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if 'blockedWidthSize' is less than or equal to zero */
    public BlockedWidthList(int blockedWidthSize){
        if(blockedWidthSize<1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width must be a positive number");
        this.blockedWidthSize = blockedWidthSize;
    }

    public final int blockedWidthSize;

    private List<T> internal = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(T elem){
        internal.add(elem);
    }

    /** Access a row in the blocked width list by a row index. Indexing starts at 0
      *
      * @return A list containing up to 'blockedWidthSize' elements
      * @throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException if the row does not exist
      */
    public List<T> getRow(int rowIndex){
        if (rowIndex < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Negative row");
        int startIdx = rowIndex * blockedWidthSize;
        return internal.subList(startIdx, startIdx + blockedWidthSize);
    }
}
```

You can see that, under the hood, this class only uses a list and an integer. `Add` simply forwards the call to the underlying list.

The method you are probably interested in is `getRow`. Let's think about where the `i`th row can be found in the list.

- The first row is always at index 0, since we are appending elements at the end.
- The second row starts after removing `blockWidthSize` number of elements. Since we are 0 indexed, the second row starts at index `blockWidthSize`
- If you think about it, the first element of the `i`th row is at index `i * blockWidthSize`.

We then simply return the `subList` starting at the computed index and ending `blockedWidthSize` elements later.

**Edit**: Obviously, this interface is fairly useless: A client can not know whether he can access a certain row unless he either knows all elements that were put into the list, or if he catches the exception thrown when accessing an invalid row. This means, in the minimum you should add a method to the interface that exposes information about the **size** of the list. This could simply be the number of elements (i.e., forwarding a call to `internal.size()`, or the number of rows (which requirs some computations, but is not too hard to do)

Comment: The ArrayList must be 2D: ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>

Comment: Why does the implementation detail matter? If you want, you can always define an iterator over the `BlockedWidthList` and store each element in a `List`.