# How to convert a 2D ArrayList to a 2D String?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, arraylist

I'm trying to convert my 2D ArrayList "dataArrayList" to a 2D String array so that I can sort it alphabetically, but it's giving me a warning when I try, saying:

```
Suspicious Collection.toArray() call. Collection item type java.util.List<java.lang.String> 
is not assignable to array component type java.lang.String[]
```

And when I try to run it, it fails. Here is my code:

```
public static List<List<String>> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        readFile();
        alphaSort();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void readFile() {
    FileReader fileRead = new FileReader(txtFileDirectory);
    BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(fileRead);
    String line = "";

    for (int i = 0; line != null; i ++) {
        line = dataReader.readLine();
        if (line != null)
            dataArrayList.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(",");
    }
}

public static void alphaSort() {
    String[][] alphaArray = new String[dataArrayList.Size()][15]

    //warning underline on "alphaArray"
    dataArrayList.toArray(alphaArray);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert ArrayList into 2D array containing varying lengths of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043209/convert-arraylist-into-2d-array-containing-varying-lengths-of-arrays)

Comment: Welp, apparently the mods don't think so. See if my answer below works for you anyways I suppose. (It compiles and seems to work just fine for me.)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: looks like this has already been done: [Convert ArrayList into 2D array containing varying lengths of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043209/convert-arraylist-into-2d-array-containing-varying-lengths-of-arrays).

You are getting an error as you need to convert both levels of `List` to `array`. Try looping through your list and convert each sublist to an array.

```
public static void alphaSort() {
    String[][] alphaArray = new String[dataArrayList.Size()][15];
    for(int i = 0; i < dataArrayList.size(); i++)
        alphaArray[i] = dataArrayList.get(i).toArray(new String[15]);
}
```

The second answer of the above linked question provides an alternate method to the one I have presented above:

```
public static void alphaSort() {
    ArrayList<String[]> tempList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (ArrayList<String> stringList : dataArrayList)
        tempList.add(stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]));

    String[][] alphaArray = tempList.toArray(new String[dataArrayList.size()][]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list to 2-dimensional array you have to traverse inside a list and assign each element to the array.

Here I write a transformer for you;

```
public static String[][] transformListToArray(List<List<String>> inputList) {

    int rows = inputList.size();
    int columns = inputList.get(0).size();

    String[][] array2d = new String[rows][columns];

    for( int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++ )
        for( int j = 0; j < inputList.get(i).size(); j++ )
            array2d[i][j] = inputList.get(i).get(j);

    return array2d;
}
```

Printing is also similiar, only you have to traverse inside the array and format the output;

I also wrote this one for printing the 2-dimensional array;

```
public static void print2DArray( String[][] inputArray) {

    for( int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++ ) {

        for( int j = 0; j < inputArray[i].length; j++ )
            System.out.printf("%s ", inputArray[i][j]);

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

As a complete solution, you can check this out, it's working fine;

```
public class TestConvert2DArray {

    public static List<List<String>> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            readFile();
            // alphaSort(); we dont need it anymore
            String new2dArray[][] = transformListToArray(dataArrayList);
            print2DArray(new2dArray);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    // To be used on transforming the list to 2d-array
    public static String[][] transformListToArray(List<List<String>> inputList) {

        int rows = inputList.size();
        int columns = inputList.get(0).size();

        String[][] array2d = new String[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < inputList.get(i).size(); j++)
                array2d[i][j] = inputList.get(i).get(j);

        return array2d;
    }

    // To be used on printing the 2d-array to the console
    public static void print2DArray(String[][] inputArray) {

        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < inputArray[i].length; j++)
                System.out.printf("%s ", inputArray[i][j]);

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    // Just added an init for textFileDirectory
    public static void readFile() throws Exception {
        String txtFileDirectory = "D:\\try.txt"; // "D:\\try.txt"
        FileReader fileRead = new FileReader(txtFileDirectory);
        BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(fileRead);
        String line = "";

        // And you dont need and index inside the for loop
        for (; line != null;) {
            line = dataReader.readLine();
            if (line != null)
                dataArrayList.add(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
        }

        dataReader.close(); // You have to close all the reasources to prevent
                            // data leak
    }

}
```

A sample input is same with the input file;

```
01 - What comes around, goes around
02 - Eyes wide open
03 - What comes around, goes around
04 - Eyes wide open
05 - What comes around, goes around
06 - Eyes wide open
07 - What comes around, goes around
08 - Eyes wide open
09 - What comes around, goes around
10 - Eyes wide open
```