# Java 3d Arraylist into a 3d Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How would I transform a 3 dimensional `ArrayList` into a 3 dimensional array? I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043209/convert-arraylist-into-2d-array-containing-varying-lengths-of-arrays/34744176#34744176) post about turning a 2-D `ArrayList` into a 2-D array and I wondered how to extend the answer to 3-D.

Comment: u mean this :  `int[][][] --> ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>`

Comment: I ment  ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> --> int[][][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the answer of the original post you refer to. I just extended it to three dimensions:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> input;
  String[][][]                            output;
  String[][]                              tmp;
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>            lvl2;
  ArrayList<String>                       lvl3;

  input = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
  input.add(new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>());
  input.get(0).add(new ArrayList<String>());
  input.get(0).get(0).add("foobar");

  output = new String[input.size()][][];
  for (int outer = 0; outer < input.size(); ++outer) {
    lvl2 = input.get(outer);
    tmp  = new String[lvl2.size()][];
    for (int inner = 0; inner < lvl2.size(); ++inner) {
      lvl3       = lvl2.get(inner);
      tmp[inner] = lvl3.toArray(new String[lvl3.size()]);
    }
    output[outer] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. That was the answer I was searching for.

Comment: I'd suggest to also take a look at the answer of @Erik Nyström.

Answer (score 6):

This is the fantastic thing with the new functional interface:

```
String[][][] stringArray = mainList.stream().map(u1 -> u1.stream().map(u2 -> u2.toArray(new String[0])).toArray(String[][]::new)).toArray(String[][][]::new);
```

would probably work. Sadly, I have currently no access to a JRE 8 to test it, but it should chain nicely.

Simply map an additional time to propagate the arrays outward.

This works so well thanks to the way arrays works in java. An `int[][]` array is actually an array of `int[]` arrays. If arrays were declared with the generics notation, this would mean that an integer array with two dimensions would be of type `Array<Array<Integer>>`, and so on. What the map functions does is simply utilizing this fact, and maps the `ArrayList<>` objects into these "`Array<>`" objects.

We simply have to do it the correct number of times.

Comment: Are you aware of [ideone](https://ideone.com/)? It offers an editor, an online compiler and a runner for a pretty big set of languages. I may be wrong but I think they support java7 to.

Comment: I meant java8. And yes. They support sun-jdk-8u51.

Comment: I just tested this (and made a minor syntax edit). Works like a charm.

Comment: @lupz Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you arraylist is like:
A{B{C}} where:

```
A1 = {
    B1={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cx}, 
    B2={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cy},
    ...
    Bm1={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cz}
A2 = {
    B1={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cx}, 
    B2={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cy},
    ...
    Bm2={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cz}
...
An = {
    B1={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cx}, 
    B2={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cy},
    ...
    Bmn={C1, C2, C3, ..., Cz}
```

to convert this arrayList to 3d array first get the proper lengths of that array

for dimension 1 proper length is size of ArrayList A => n.

for dimension 2 proper length is the max length of all B => max(m)

for dimension 3 proper length is the max length of all C => max (x,y,z)

then you can fill your array by looping through the ArrayList.

Unless if you are using Java8, there are probably more fancy ways to do it.